# JRuby 1.7.1 and PsychParser error parsing UTF-8 YAML file (Rails 3.2.8)

Tags: jruby, yaml, jrubyonrails, psychparser

In our JRuby/Rails project, we are using the `i18n` gem, and support Japanese as well as English. Our `config/locales.ja.yml` file is in UTF-8, without any BOM.

When running `Rails 3.2.9` on `JRuby 1.7.1`, we now see the following error:

```
% jruby -S rake spec:models

 Psych::SyntaxError: (C:/Projects/foobar/trunk/config/locales/ja.yml): 
   expected <block end>, but found Scalar while parsing a block 
   mapping at line 7 column 33

   parse at org/jruby/ext/psych/PsychParser.java:213
   ...
```

This error for YAML parsing the `ja.yml` file is now happening on both our Windows XP and Linux development environments, and *only seems to go away when we explicitly set the following system parameter for the JVM*:

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

**Could anyone tell me why this is happening on `JRuby 1.7.1`?** 
I didn't see this in `1.6.8` or `1.7.0`.

Comment: Faced same thing with Jruby1.7, Rails 3.2.13 under Windows but without error or exception, just garpish text instead of Arabic .. running `SET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"` worked for me too

Comment: Happens to be a bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7142; fixed since 1.7.5

Comment: @ted "fixed since 1.7.5"? It still appears that the latest release to date is 1.7.4...

Comment: 1.7.5 is available at https://github.com/jruby/jruby, from sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over a year old now, but here is the answer:

http://jruby.org/2012/12/03/jruby-1-7-1.html

In that release, this happened:

- Psych YAML engine updated to latest